# Returning to a view in a Tab Bar Controller Programatically

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I have a TabBarController with 5 ViewControllers within it, on one of the ViewControllers, I have a set of buttons which load different view controllers outside of the TabBarController. These are loaded though the Modal Segue's, however the issue I am having is when I try to go back to the View within the Tab Bar it loads but without the Tab Bar itself, the code I have is:

```
class GreetingsVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {

        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("anonScreen") as! AnonVC
        self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

How can I make it so when the back button is pressed it presents the View Controller from the Tab Bar Controller?

Comment: Try to do `self.tabBarController.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)` instead of `self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)`

Comment: nope, still loads the view without the Tab Bar at the bottom :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, from the tabbar controller, you have present the GreetingsVC using `presentViewController` and you want to go back to previous view (one of the tabbar view controllers)

Instead of using `presentViewController`, you need to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated`

```
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: just tried it and still not showing the tab bar on dismiss :/ thanks for the suggestion though! Appreciate it

Comment: what do you use from button to GreetingsVC? modal or show? I assume you are using storyboard segue

Comment: the GreetingsVC is accessed by using a storyboard segue on modal

Comment: I updated my code, just keep that one line in `goBack` function. let me know if still there is issue

Comment: That's what i tried doing before and it didn't work. Thanks anyway

Comment: i see. then there should not be any issue if dismiss properly. sure welcome

Comment: It dismisses the view controller but when it returns to the anonScreen the tab bar is no longer at the bottom of the view controller

Comment: i'm an idiot xD I was testing the wrong button >.< I'm sorry! It worked like a dream man! Thank you so much :l idiot points go to me